# Containing a hair's shape within a mesh, even with vertex groups: Is it possible?

Tags: vertex-groups, hair, collision

Is there any way to contain the shape of hair within a mesh? Would it need vertex groups for more than density? I want to put hair inside a mesh, make the mesh invisible while containing the hair, then have the hair follow along with the shape of the mesh.

Comment: Hello. Which kind of shape do you want ?

Comment: I want to make a wig mesh, then fit the hair inside of it, forcing it to conform.

Comment: so a wig but any kind of shape ?

Comment: Yes, and that it shapes and contains hair particles.